# if statement with or

Tags: c#, if-statement, xna

Can any body tell me what I'm doing wrong?
i have 4 values (3 random and 1 unique) what I'm trying to do is make sure i have no duplicates so i figured an if statement should do the trick can anybody tell me if this is the way to do it?
I have been getting duplicates but not sure if the if statement isn't doing its job or something else.

```
if (value1 == answer | value1 == value2 | value1 == value3)
{
    value1 = ans.Next(1, 40); 
}
if (value2 == answer | value2 == value1 | value2 == value3)
{
    value2 = ans.Next(1, 40); 
}
if (value3 == answer | value3 == value2 | value3 == value1)
{
    value3 = ans.Next(1, 40); 
}
```

Comment: Well what's to stop you from getting the same thing again from `ans.Next`?

Comment: The code is in update so i would presume it would change it again?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. But I suspect you want to use `while` loops...

Answer (score 0):

A single `|` is a binary OR, you want double `||` for a logical OR.

```
if (value1 == answer || value1 == value2 || value1 == value3)
```

Comment: I can only repeat what has been told to me in my (now deleted answer) this is not correct. _The | operator is perfectly legal on Booleans as well as integers_

Comment: Perfectly legal is not the same as "doing what the programmer wanted". An empty main would be perfectly legal, too. I would be surprised if the binary operators short-circuit for example.

Comment: `if(true | false | false)` ? I think that, in  this case, there is no difference.

Comment: If you want them binary or'ed together and the result evaluated by the if, sure. If you want them evaluated one by one, stopping when you find the first true because that would make the result true, then no, it's not the same. If you only look at the result, sure, it's the same. It would have been the same if you just omitted the if alltogether. Same result. Different program.

Comment: This is not what I mean, the condition `value1 == answer` is a boolean, and same for the next ones, the logical OR applied to a boolean vs a boolean produces the same result as the conditional OR. Thus from the question point of view, your answer cannot produce a different result from the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe approach this slightly differently. Instead of having three random numbers generated, I'd have an array of integers between 1 and 40, and shuffle them using [Fisher-Yates](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle). Then just take the top three.

```
//assuming 'answer' is your constant value
var allValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 40).Where(x => x != answer).ToArray();
Shuffle(allValues);
value1 = allValues[0];
value2 = allValues[1];
value3 = allValues[2];
```

The shuffle algorithm from the site linked above

```
private static Random _random = new Random();
public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
{
    var random = _random;
    for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        // Pick random element to swap.
        int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
        // Swap.
        T tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Since you're shuffling existing numbers, it avoids having to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a while loop:

```
while (value1 == answer || value1 == value2 || value1 == value3)
{
   value1 = ans.Next(1,40);
}
```